# How can I modify left property after hide an element using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I am trying to achieve it is to move an elemement (an image) with `left` property after I hide a div.

To do that, I use `.promise()` function of JQuery. Here is my code:

**HTML** code:

```
<div id="outerContainer">
  <div id="left"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="div1" class="square red"></div>
    <div id="div2" class="square green">
      <img id="image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a">
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="square blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** code:

```
#outerContainer{
   display: flex;
   height: 100vh;
}

#left{
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: #e0e0d1;
}

#container{
  display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 2;
}

#right{
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #354551;
}
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.green{
  background-color: green;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.square{
  flex: 1 0 10%;
    height: 50px;
}

#image{
  position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width:50px; 
    height:50px;
    left: 30px;
}

#div2{
  position: relative;
}
```

**JQuery** code:

```
$('#left').click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

$("#left").promise().done(function(){
     $("#image").css({left: "+=" + 30});
     //$("#image").css({left: "+=" + 30 + "px"}); Same behaviour as before

});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wopacpkr/) in which you can prove it.

After removing the `left` element, I would like to move the image `30px` more to the right (so I will have to add pixels to the left) but I need to wait until the left element have been removed totally (it is the reason why I use `.promise()` function).

It seems that `.promise()` function it is blocking the browser because the `left` property never changes.

How can I modify left property of an element after that the element that I had removed have been hidden totally?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "The .promise() method returns a dynamically generated Promise that is resolved once all actions of a certain type bound to the collection, queued or not, have ended.

By default, type is "fx", which means the returned Promise is resolved when all animations of the selected elements have completed."

Comment: @j08691 But here I just have `.hide()` function that affects to the `left` div. I supposed that it finished after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you insist on using the `promise()` function, but if not, you could also use a callback in the [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function, which is called after hiding completes, like this:

```
$('#left').click(function() {
    $(this).hide(0, function()
    {
        $("#image").css({left: "+=" + 30}); 
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wopacpkr/1/)

Comment: No, I did not insist on using the `.promise()` function. Thank you for providing a solution without using any function!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#left").promise().done(function(){
   $("#image").css({left: $("#image").position().left + 30});
});
```

Comment: What I wanted was to move the image after hide the left div. Not to move it before hide the div. Anyway, thank you for answer the question!